# @ variable in mysqli statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm now sitting for hours and trying to pass multiple queries through my PHP script.

Basically, I'd like to query for the last inserted index in the address folder, then save the index as a variable "@address", so that I can use it in the next query, etc.

The SQL script works fine, however, as soon as I use it in my PHP script, it doesn't insert any new data.

Also I don't want to split it into multiple single queries, because this script will be used in a web application, where a lot of new registrations will be processed and therefore it is important, that when two customer register at the same time, it is ensured that the foreign keys will be assigned in the right way.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "test", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = 'SET @address = (select max(idaddress) from test.address) + 1; SET @customer= (select max(idcustomer) from test.customer) + 1;
        SET @contract= (select max(idcontact) from test.contract) + 1;
        INSERT INTO `test`.`address` (`idaddress`, `street`, `number`, `zip`) VALUES (@address, "main street", "584", "54545");
        INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`idcustomer`, `name`, `surname`, `customeraddress`) VALUES (@customer, "Smith", "Michael", @address);
        INSERT INTO `test`.`contract` (`idcontract`, `customernumber`) VALUES (@contract, @costumer);
       ';
echo $query; // for testing purposes
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }

    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

c0mplexity

Comment: If you don't want to split the query into multiple single queries,why are you using `mysqli_multi_query`.Simply use `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation wasn't good enough. I meant that I don't want to use more complex queries via     mysql_query. Thus, I use the @ variables and process multiple queries in one run.

Comment: If you want to use `mysqli_multi_query`,you need to assign multiple queries to single variable `$query` 1 by 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
As you can see from my source code, it did this wihin the $query variable. Within this variable, there are 6 queries. The problem is, that nothing changes after running the PHP script.

So I wonder, whether my PHP script is wrong or whether it is not possible to use sql @ variables in a PHP script.

Comment: Try the answer once.

Comment: Your script will **not** guarantee that foreign keys are assigned correctly. If multiple simultaneous requests come in, you can't tell in which order those requests will be handled. But you can be sure that it will handle part of one request and then part of another request.

Comment: Also, you need to [check for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) when you execute a query. Those errors (if any) will help you identify the reason why the query has failed.

Comment: Thank you, Arjan. What can be done to ensure, that in case of simultaneous requests the foreign keys will be assigned correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of yours.Hope it will work for you.

```
$query = "SET @address = (select max(idaddress) from test.address) + 1"; 
$query = "SET @customer= (select max(idcustomer) from test.customer) + 1";
$query = "SET @contract= (select max(idcontact) from test.contract) + 1";
$query = "INSERT INTO `test`.`address` (`idaddress`, `street`, `number`, `zip`) VALUES (@address, 'main street', "584", "54545")";
$query = "INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`idcustomer`, `name`, `surname`, `customeraddress`) VALUES (@customer, 'Smith', 'Michael', @address)";
$query = "INSERT INTO `test`.`contract` (`idcontract`, `customernumber`) VALUES (@contract, @costumer)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I added a dot before the equal sign.

Unfortunately, it doesen't work :( The SQL script works perfectly in phpmyadmin, but not in my PHP script :/